# Vim text substituion

Tags: vim

When I use the command **:%s/or/and/g** to replace **'or'** with **'and'**, Vim is altering the word color, i.e. (col(**or**)) to make it col(**and**), meaning, its changing the word color to coland and I don't need Vim to do this.

In such a scenario, which command should I use to alter 'or' to an 'and' and let the string 'color' be untouched?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`or` matches the two characters no matter where they are so it will match `or` in `or`, `for`, `normal`, `color`, etc.

If you only want to match the *word* `or`, then you need to wrap your pattern in "word boundaries":

```
:%s/\<or\>/and/g
```

Which tells Vim that `or` should begin and end a "word" as defined by `:help 'iskeyword'`.

See `:help \<` and `:help \>`.

Comment: Many thanks sir. That command works exactly as I wanted. And I also thank you for the additional help section pointer, I will go through it.